# Broken live mp3 stream from Icecast using mediaelement.js

Tags: safari, streaming, mp3, mediaelement.js, icecast

I'm using mediaelement.js to live stream our radio station in mp3 format from Icecast. All is fine, except for odd reports that the stream won't play in certain browsers. I've verified that it won't play in Safari 5.1.7/Windows (but who uses that anyway?). Far more troubling are reports from users on Windows 7/Firefox or Chrome, although I can't duplicate that problem myself.

The Icecast stream is using port 8000 and I wonder if there could be firewall issues in some places blocking that port. But that wouldn't account for the Safari/Windows issue.

Anyone know what the deal here could be?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: It's hard to help you without more information.  Can you at least provide a link to the page?  Port 8000 is problematic for some users, but mainly those behind corporate firewalls.  You can stream on port 80.